# Proof Verification - Set Theory Inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Disprove the following statement:

$$(A\cap B)\cap C = \emptyset\iff A\cap C = \emptyset \land B\cap C = \emptyset$$

For my proof that the above is not true, I first assume it is true and try to prove it, then show the proof is not sufficient, then raise a valid counter example. I realize just raising a valid counterexample should be good enough but I want more practice working with logic and proof writing.

$$\begin{align}
(A\cap B)\cap C = \emptyset ~\iff~ & \text{the following two conditions hold:}
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \text{1.) } \forall x\in A\cap B,\text{holds } x\notin C
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& (x\in A ~\wedge~ x\notin C)~\wedge~(x\in B ~\wedge~ x\notin C)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& (x\notin A\cap C) ~\wedge~ (x\notin B\cap C)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \neg((x\in A\cap C) ~\vee~ (x\in B\cap C))
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \neg(x \in (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)) \text{ (definition of union)}
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& x \notin (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& (A\cap C) = \emptyset, (B\cap C) = \emptyset
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \text{as well as}
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \text{2.) } \forall x\in C,\text{holds } x\notin A\cap B
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& (x\in C)~\wedge~(x\notin A\cap B)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& (x\in C)~\wedge~\neg(x\in A\cap B)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& (x\in C)~\wedge~\neg(x\in A ~\wedge~ x\in B)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& (x\in C)~\wedge~(x\notin A ~\vee~ x\notin B)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& (x\notin A ~\wedge~ x\in C)~\vee~(x\notin B ~\wedge~ x\in C) \text{ (distributive law) }
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& (x\notin A\cap C)~\vee~(x\notin B\cap C)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \neg((x\in A\cap C)~\wedge~(x\in B\cap C))
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \neg(x \in (A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C)) \text{ (definition of intersection) }
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& x \notin (A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \text{not sufficient enough to say both } (A\cap C) = \emptyset \text{ and } (B\cap C) = \emptyset
\end{align}$$

Consider the following counter example:

$$A = \{1, 2\}, B = \{3, 4\}, C = \{2, 3\}$$

In this situation $(A\cap B)\cap C = \emptyset$ however $A\cap C = \{2\}$ and $B\cap C = \{3\}$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: " I first assume it is true and try to prove it, then show the proof is not sufficient"  ....????.... I may not understand what you mean but showing that *one* proof isn't sufficient doesn't mean a statement isn't true.  It just means your proof is faulty.  Suppose I were asked to prove "if n is an even number, then $4|n^2$" and I said "If n = 4k it is even so 4|n so 4|n^2" and someone pointed out that proof wasn't sufficient.  That doesn't mean the proposition is false.  It *is* true.  I just failed to prove it is all.

Comment: @fleablood I see what you're saying. Let me try and explain better. I am trying to show that if the original proposition is true, one of two conditions will be met for all x, which means each condition much show the original proposition, (A intersect C) is empty and (B intersect C) is empty, is true for all x that meet that condition. I then show that one of the conditions (2nd in the proof in my question) does not necessarily mean original proposition is true for all x that meet this condition

Comment: @fleablood however the more I think about it, the smallest counter example is probably more valid than lack of proof. I guess I'm trying to make my failed proof into evidence of an invalid proposition by showing that then only way the proposition could be valid is if this proof is correct since it covers all outcomes

Comment: It's valid to try to see what the proposition implies and what it doesn't imply.  But it's not enough to say it fails to prove so it isn't true; but we can say "as this isn't implied lets see if we can use it to find a counter example".  Ex: $A \cap B \cap C \implies$ A and $B\capC$ are dijoint but not that either are empty.  Let's let B \cap C not empty but A disjoint from B\cap C and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to practice with proof and logic consider:

Let $(A \cap B)\cap C = \emptyset$

$(A \cap B) \cap C = A \cap (B \cap C) = \emptyset$

So $A$ and $B\cap C$ are disjoint.  But we have no reason to assume either are empty.  We could easily have $b \in B; b\in C;b \not \in A; A = \emptyset$.

That $(A \cap B)\cap C = \emptyset$ and $B \cap C \ne \emptyset$

So $(A \cap B)\cap C = \emptyset \not \implies  A\cap C = \emptyset \land B\cap C = \emptyset$.

Comment: Ok, the furthest I got with this is here: [latex](https://s21.postimg.io/48cn32bvb/Screenshot_from_2016_09_05_19_45_57.png). This obviously says that there exists an $x$ on either $A\cap C$ or $B\cap C$ or possibly both which I believe does imply that they are both not empty. Is this good enough?